# How to combine simple JQuery autocomplete syntax with ajax call to remote data source (PHP script)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

I have a functioning JQuery autocomplete script that calls a PHP script that queries a database, loops through the results, inserts them into an array, then this function echos that array json_encoded and autocomplete works great:

Example A:

```
$(function() {
        var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;
        $( "#Person" ).autocomplete({
            dataType: "json",
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

However, with this approach, all of the names in $names are visible in the page source. I have another functioning autocomplete script that utilizes ajax:

Example B:

```
$("#Person").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PHPscript",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#Person-suggestion-box").show();
            $("#Person-suggestion-box").html(data);
        }
        });
    });
```

The difference, however, is that I have to manually style the Person-suggestion-box and hand-code many of the intricacies that are bundled very functionally into the simple JQuery autocomplete. Is there a way to utilize Example A with the functionality of Example B (so that I have the simple CSS and functionality that comes with JQuery autocomplete, but with the privacy of results of Example B (not visible in source)? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: doesn't the documentation have an example using ajax? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: tried it ... not working ...

Comment: Why didn't it work? In what way didn't it work? How did it not work? Did any errors occur? did you look at the ajax response in the console? did you make sure the server is responding with the format that autocomplete is expecting?

Comment: that's the question! json_encode($php_array) right? My PHP script echos json_encode($php_array). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean the array is in the right format. Don't ask me what the right format is either, i don't know, i'd have to look at the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

How about echoing the `$names` into a div element, copy all contents from that div into a javascript variable and afterwards remove the div and all its names inside from the DOM (and source),

PHP:

```
<div class="names"><?php echo json_encode($names) ?></div>
```

JS:

```
// copy names from the div
var availableTags = $('div.names').html();

// remove div
$('div.names').remove();

// add content to autocomplete
$("#Person").autocomplete({
    dataType: "json",
    source: availableTags
});
```

**Edit:**

The div needs to be empty in the beginning. Only after the page load has finished, use an ajax call (similar to the one in Example B) to get the names and then add them to `<div class="names"></div>`,

```
$('div.names').html(data);
```

afterwards continue as per the first suggestion,

```
// copy names from the div
var availableTags = $('div.names').html();

// remove div
$('div.names').remove();

// add content to autocomplete
$("#Person").autocomplete({
    dataType: "json",
    source: availableTags
});
```

Comment: we need to make sure the div is empty when the page is loaded and dynamically get the names after, see my edit above

Comment: note that sticking a json string inside an html element like this can mangle your json if you aren't careful.

Comment: and... Why would you, after ajax, stick the result in the DOM, and then pull it back out of the DOM? that makes no sense. just keep it in a variable.